# RecycleView with fragments

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-inflate

I'm trying to implement a vertical RecycleList with fill_parent width fragments which contains another RecyclerView but horizontal.[image]

I'm getting this error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
```

Thats is the question:
1) Is it a good way to implement a list inside a list?
2) Why am I getting this exception?

Code:

```
VerticalList (fragment_recommendation_layout.xml)

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAppBg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cardList"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_recommendation_vertical_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

Vertical list item (fragment_recommendation_vertical_list.xml)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Row Title" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:name="br.com.leanworks.fiquepordentro.view.recommendations.RecommendationHorizontalFragment"
        android:layout_height="259dp" />
</LinearLayout>



Vertical adapter(RecommendationVerticalListViewAdapter.java)

@Override
    public RecommendationItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View itemView;
        RecommendationItemViewHolder recommendationItemViewHolder;

        itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.fragment_recommendation_vertical_list, viewGroup, false);

        recommendationItemViewHolder = new RecommendationItemViewHolder(itemView);

        return recommendationItemViewHolder;
    }


Exception:

    10-18 06:08:12.936 12006-12006/br.com.leanworks.fiquepordentro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: br.com.leanworks.fiquepordentro, PID: 12006
                                                                                     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                         at br.com.leanworks.fiquepordentro.view.recommendations.RecommendationVerticalListViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecommendationVerticalListViewAdapter.java:78)
                                                                                         at br.com.leanworks.fiquepordentro.view.recommendations.RecommendationVerticalListViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecommendationVerticalListViewAdapter.java:25)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5833)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your RecyclerView's adapter:

```
//where FRAGMENT is your int id
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (listItems.get(position) instanceof MyClass)
        return FRAGMENT;
    ...
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

    switch (viewType) {
        case FRAGMENT:
            View fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderFragment(fragView);
            break;
        ...
    }

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case FRAGMENT:
            final ViewHolderFragment holder = (ViewHolderFragment) viewHolder;
            //bad idea 
    }
}
```

---

The ViewHolderFragment class:

```
public class ViewHolderFragment extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
//framelayout to contain the fragment
private FrameLayout frameLayout;

public ViewHolderFragment(View v) {
    super(v);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.container);
}

public FrameLayout getFrameLayout() {
    return frameLayout;
}

public void setFrameLayout(FrameLayout frameLayout) {
    this.frameLayout = frameLayout;
}
```

}

---

In your my_layout.xml is only the FrameLayout to contain the fragment:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Almost there, but I got only one fragment replaced with this code. Also .replace() expects an ID and not a Fragment. I did not use the override on GetItemViewType and the switchs. It there a problem? Thank you for your time!

Comment: No. If your recycler view only contains one type of row, there's no need to switch the return type. Sorry, my bad: holder.getFrameLayout().getId() should do the work.

Comment: thanks for you reply. Unfortunitly it still not working. Is:  ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(rssItemViewHolder.frameLayout.getId(), new RecommendationHorizontalFragment(), "TAG").commitAllowingStateLoss(); a wrong call? I'm getting only ONE fragment being replaced.

Comment: Yes, that's very wrong. I think you don't understand fragments. Imagine a fragment like a view which has it's own life cycle (you can even add it on your XML layout with <fragment>). You need to create a new instance of it and add it into a view group. You can't just open or bring a fragment like an activity to front.

Comment: But what is the difference between what I've done and the code example that you gave to me?

Comment: I've been thinking a lot and after reading RecyclerView's docs, I found what you're trying to do is not a good idea because you're not recycling any view. Maybe try using a LinearLayout and add a FrameLayout to it for every fragment you need.

Comment: Got it. I aborted this approach using fragments and then I've implemented a RecyclerView. On the Adapter(vertical) I'm managing the horizontals RecyclerViews, without fragments.